# Grep words containg 'n' number of letters given user input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I am trying to create a script (bash) that will take input (integer) from a user and grep all words containing that number of letters. I am okay with how grep basically works, but I am unsure how use input from user to determine the output

Here is what I started:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo " Content type: text/html"
echo

x=`expr $1`
```

I'm pretty sure the grep command would be as simple as grep^...*integer from user*$. Just don't know how to take use the user input. Thanks!

EDIT:  I should have mentioned that "user input" would be entered as an argument (./script 6)

Comment: `read variablename` ??

Answer (score 3):

Run this script as `./script 6` and it will select all 6-letter words from the file `text` and display them:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -Eo "\<[[:alpha:]]{$1}\>" text
```

Key parts of the regex:

- `\<` signifies the start of a word.
- `[[:alpha:]]{$1}` signifies `$1` alphabetical characters.  If you want an apostrophe, such as in `don't`, to be considered a valid word character, then add it inside the outer square backets like this: `[[:alpha:]']{$1}`
- `\>` signifies the end of a word.

There are some limitations to `grep`'s ability to understand human-language.  For example, in the string `don't`, it considers the apostrophe to be a word boundary.

#### Example

I ran this script against the text of the question:

```
$ ./script.sh 9
basically
determine
mentioned
$ ./script.sh 10
containing
```

Comment: This works although I will have to read up as I am unfamiliar with the [[:alpha:]] Thanks!

Comment: @swam In the olden days with 26-letter alphabets, the regex for alphabetical characters would have been `[a-zA-Z]`.  With UTF8 and the modern explosion of characters and the no-longer-contiguous ordering of characters, new ways of expressing the requirement were required.  `[:alpha:]` means alphabetical in this new world. Some documentation on `alpha` and related classes is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `read` to accpet input from the user.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1 | grep ".\{$2\}"
```

now if yo call the script as `./script hello 5`

The positional parameters `$1` will be `hello` and `$2` as `5`

here the `{m}` matches lines with `m` lenght as `.` any character is matched for exactly `m` times

Comment: I phrased my question wrong. What I intend to do is take an argument at the command line (./script 6)

Comment: @nu11p01n73R but without anchors, it effectively means "n or more"

Comment: @o11c {n,} means n or more without the comma `,` , `{n}` means excat `n`

Comment: @nu11p01n73R but without `-o`, `grep` still outputs the whole line, even if only part of it was logically part of the match.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I think I follow on this. However I just want to enter a number ./script 6, and run against a word list that will produce all 6 letter words

Comment: Ok from where would we read the word list to run `./script 6` use just use `grep "\{$1\}`

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I will be referencing it as a variable in the script. I tried the grep "\{$1\} but it returns more than 6 letter words. However I just tried the -o flag o11c suggested and this works as well! Thank you